# Issue with submitting form as email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to submit a form as an email through PHP **but** I'm sending the data through an AJAX function call in jQuery so the page itself doesn't refresh (in short, the user fills out the form and then when they hit submit, it sets the data to a variable and sends that to the PHP page via AJAX call, all without the page reloading) but for some reason, the emails aren't sending, but the code itself seems to function?

Here's the code that I have (just the AJAX call and the php code).

```
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + "&subject=" + subject +  '&msg=' + msg;
$.ajax ({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "process.php",  
            data: dataString,  
            success: function() {  
                $("#success").show();
                $( '#contactUs' ).each(function(){
                    this.reset();
                });
            }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "xxx@someplace.net";
    $email_subject = "subject";

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['msg']; // required

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);  

?>
```

Comment: Common problem: are you sure the server you use is sending emails?

Comment: Common problem #2: why are you sending `data` as a string rather than `{object}` or `$.serialize`?

Comment: did you check the server's mail log?  do you know for sure they aren't sending?  Maybe try without the optional headers

Comment: **Joe T (and Brian)** I'm not entirely sure HOW to check, I used a valid email and since I'm running it on WAMP and I have access to the internet so I figured it would actually send the e-mail straight out - I haven't the foggiest on how to actually check the mail log for something like that.

**Brian:** I'm not sure what you mean by sending "Data" as a string, if you're referring to the AJAX call, I figured since all the data was a String, it'd be best to send it that way.

Comment: look in '/var/log' for a file called maillog or mail.log and then you can use `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` to look at the most recent few lines.  While that's going, submit your form.  Then hit 'ctrl + c' to stop tailing and get back to a prompt.

Comment: @JoeT I found out that my local server can't actually send mail (I'd have to connect to my ISP and that's a bit more hassle than I'd like to go through) so I'm gonna just upload it to the host and then run it to see if it works.

Comment: **@JoeT (and Brian)** Just so you can know, I did figure out how to get it working (took a lot of fiddling!) but I ended up noticing there were some code errors in the php (if you look close, you'll notice I forgot a closing bracket at the end).  But thanks for the help regardless!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this syntax for posting your variables as an object

```
$.ajax ({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "process.php",
        dataType: 'json'  
        data: {
            dataString : name,
            email : email,
            subject :subject,
            msg : msg
        },  
        success: function() {  
            $("#success").show();
            $( '#contactUs' ).each(function(){
                this.reset();
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Would it be better using `dataType: 'json'` and `JSON.stringify` on that data object?

Comment: For the record, this doesn't seem to let me run the "success" portion of the ajax code - it just seems to skip over it entirely - the email still sends though.  I'm guessing it's because the result I'm getting from the function isn't JSON format, which means I'd have to format it as such...